# How to heal heroes and armies?

Tags: endless-legend

Sometimes, damaged units and heroes seem to regain life.  But I really have no idea how: I don't have any technology or skill that I know for that.

How does heal work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this Steam thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/540739861193503930/#c540739861741815463):

> Every units (apart the broken lords' ones) heal over time, the
>   regeneration is faster on your regions and even faster if you stand in
>   an hex of city.

For races with the Broken Lords trait that causes healing from dust, you click a gold circle next to the units current HP and it heals them to full if you can afford it.

Comment: Watchtowers also heal units in hexes near them. I wonder if this is a recent addition to the game; docs from a few months ago don't mention it.

Answer (score 16):

- By default, you'll heal a very slow 5% per turn.
- Standing on a friendly city boosts this to 10% (garrisoning has the same effect; it doesn't stack).
- `Watchtowers` give you 20%, and this rises as you improve them to `Lookout Towers` and `Remotuscope Factories`

This may not be enough, though, so you can also:

- Ally yourself with the Sisters of Mercy.  Each of their villages gives +5% per turn, which can add up to a huge bonus (healing 1/3 of your hp per turn with 5 or 6 such villages).
- Get a hero (necrophages or sisters of mercy) with a skill that boosts % healing per turn).
- Win the Legendary Deed that gives you `Intelligence Corps` for a flat +20% per turn.
- Build the `Medical Center` and/or `Inoculation Station` buildings in your city (for roughly 25% total).

These would all add up to a ton of regen; really the idea is that 5% is slow enough to really cramp strategic movements, because it's a painfully long 20-turn process to heal your troops if they get badly hurt - but by the time you're up to 25% or so, troops can fully heal in a mere 3-4 turns.

So the purpose of having all these different ways to heal your troops is that they cover each other if one of them becomes unavailable - if you can't (or strategically don't want to) get the necrophage hero, you can grab a different source of regen to get by.  If the enemy grabs all the sisters-of-mercy villages, you can invest in the technologies - if you have the sisters, you can completely skip those techs/buildings and get ahead other ways.

You could stack everything for a wacky 60-70% regen per turn, but it's really not much better than 25% - by the time you reach 25% or so, you're healing in a few turns, and your meaningful military power is less about weathering repeated assaults, as it is about your units not getting killed during an individual assault - as the old saying goes, **you can't heal being dead**.

This is also because usually you're only up against a few armies; you're not withstanding some constant onslaught - if you survive to heal at all, you've almost always killed many/all of the enemy fighters in their army, and usually they only have a few armies in any given war (and will sue for peace after those die).

Answer (score 11):

After some trial and error I've found the base regeneration rate to be 5% on all regions (friendly or not). Cities grant 10% and towers 20%. I'm playing as Vaulter.