# Do units heal faster in your a garrison and your own territory?

Tags: endless-legend

Do units heal faster in your own territory?  And what about when they are in a garrison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That not exactly it. As pointed in answers of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166023/how-to-heal-heroes-and-armies), units heal a percentage of max health each turn, friendly city and watchtower only give your units an heal boost.

- 5% is the default healing.
- 10% when your troops are on a friendly city, garrison or not.
- 20% when your troops are on a watchtower.

Also, some building, heroes, factions and quests can boost your healing. Again, see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/248674/149081).